# LINQ - Grouping by left join queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have three tables as follows:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Answer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }
    public Guid AppraiserId { get; set; }//Employee who appraises
    public Guid AppraisedId { get; set; }//Employee who has been appraised
}

public class FinalizedEmployee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AppraiserId { get; set; }
    public Guid AppraisedId { get; set; }
}
```

Every employee has an entry in the answers table by default. and when they answer all the questions we add a record in FinalizedEmployees.

Now I want to write a query to show all employees whether they have answered all the questions or not.

The output will be something like this:

| Employee | Has answered all the questions |
| --- | --- |
| Employee 1 | True |
| Employee 2 | False |
| Employee 3 | True |

This is what I have tried so far:

```cs
var attendees = from answers in dbContext.Answers
            join employees in dbContext.Employees
            on answers.AppraiserId equals employees.Id
            join finalize in dbContext.FinalizedEmployees 
            on answers.AppraiserId equals finalize.AppraisedId into finalized
            from completed in finalized.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where answers.AppraisalId == request.appraisalId

            group employees by new { appraiser=answers.AppraiserId,hasComplete=completed!=null} into attendee
            select new {attendee.Key.appraiser,attendee.Key.hasComplete };
```

The output is correct but only gives me employee Ids instead of the employee itself.

How can I write this query?

Is there any better way?

Comment: Is there any relationship between `Employee` and `FinalizedEmployee` entities such as foreign key column in `FinalizedEmployee`?

Comment: Yes, both AppraiserId and AppraisedId are foreign keys in FinalizedEmployees

Comment: I can think of a couple of options: grouping on a left join (not my favorite) or using an 'exists'-style query via `Any()`. What have you tried?

Comment: I did left join . but have no idea about exists style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every employee has an entry in answers table. and if they have answered all the questions there is a record in FinalizedEmployee table.

To check whether that the `Employee` has answered all the questions, you need a LEFT JOIN query for `Employee` to `FinalizedEmployee` tables.

With LEFT JOIN:

1. Guarantee all the records from `Employee` (LEFT) table will be queried.
2. If the employee's Id exists in `FinalizedEmployee`, the `HasAnsweredAllQuestion` will be `true`.

```cs
(from a in dbContext.Employees 
join b in dbContext.FinalizedEmployees on a.Id equals b.AppraisedId into ab
from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
    HasAnsweredAllQuestion = b != null
}).ToList();
```

---

Another approach suggested by @Corey which was achieved with `EXISTS` will be:

```cs
(from a in dbContext.Employees
select new 
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
    HasAnsweredAllQuestion = dbContext.FinalizedEmployees.Any(x => x.AppraisedId == a.Id)
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I prefer the 'exists' form. It's cleaner to read and handles multiple entries in `FinalizedEmployees` without duplication in the original query. You can solve that by grouping, but that's not very efficient.

Comment: good for second part. that is much better